# Python can't find library but pycharm can

Tags: python, django-templates, include-path, geos, yandex-api

I recently added a [yandex-maps](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yandex-maps) application to my django project, fulfilling all the installation instructions. However, when I try to open the page with {% load yandex_maps_tags %} tag, I get an error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: 'yandex_maps_tags' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading yandex_maps.templatetags.yandex_maps_tags: Could not find the GEOS library (tried "geos_c", "GEOS"). Try setting GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

I didn't install a custom version of GEOS library, I didn't install it at all. However, when I click on the import line in yandex-maps library and press ⌘-B, I'm taken to GEOS's library `__init__.py` file, which is located at `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/__init__.py`. I don't know what is supposed to be a standard path for this library, but it looks like it to me.

I'm completely lost with this error. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `django.contrib.gis.geos` you need first install GEOS library. Here are the [instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#geos).

If you'll still have problems, see [Can’t find GEOS library](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#can-t-find-geos-library) django docs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I only now realised that GEOS library and django.contrib.gis.geos aren't same thing. Thanks!